# How to disable liferay control panel's file upload size limit

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

In Liferay, under Control Panel -> Server Administration, we can set the file size upload limit. This overrides the

```
dl.file.max.size
```

setting in portal-ext. Can I disable the control panel from overriding this property?

Cause I want to use a seperate instance that has no upload size limit. If I'm not wrong the setting in the control panel applies to all instances connected to the same database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find the setting in the liferay database table

```
select * from [liferay].[dbo].[PortalPreferences] where preferences like '%dl.file.max.size%';
```

We will get something like below:

```
<portlet-preferences>
 .....
 <preference>
  <name>dl.file.max.size</name>
  <value>104857600</value>
 </preference>
 <preference>
  <name>com.liferay.portal.upload.UploadServletRequestImpl.max.size</name>
  <value>524288000</value>
 </preference>
  .......
</portlet-preferences>
```

We just remove the above 2 preferences and we can set them in portal-ext.properties instead.